# how to implement react-redux in micro frontend architecture with individual MFE?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, micro-frontend, single-spa

might be question is duplicated ,even though my business case is little bit different since I need help from experts.

First time, I am using **Micro frontend architecture** in current project with help of [single spa framework](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview)

with reactjs.
I have experience in reactjs with redux(thunk,saga) but in single spa, I am unable to intercept the provider with **store** in **individual** **MFE** root component.

anybody has used reactjs with Single SPA framework along with redux with individual MFE.

my all MFE are in reactjs only.

#reactjs #redux #redux-saga.

Comment: I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented in some time back, was using redux for inter app communication between MFEs as well.

Store was build separately in child app.

This store would be imported by the master app and registered in global event distributor in the master app.

```
    class GlobalEventDistributor {
    
        constructor() {
            this.stores = [];
        }
    
        registerStore(store) {
            this.stores.push(store);
        }
    
        dispatch(event) {
            this.stores.forEach((s) => s.dispatch(event));
        }
    }
```

This GlobalEventDistributor along with the store will be passed as a custom prop while registering application.

```
    let storeModule = {},
        customProps = {
          globalEventDistributor: globalEventDistributor,
          ...additionalProps,
        };
    
      try {
        storeModule = storeURL
          ? await SystemJS.import(storeURL)
          : { storeInstance: null };
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Could not load store of app ${name}.`, e);
      }
    
      if (storeModule.storeInstance && globalEventDistributor) {
        // add a reference of the store to the customProps
        customProps.store = storeModule.storeInstance;
    
        // register the store with the globalEventDistributor
        globalEventDistributor.registerStore(storeModule.storeInstance);
      }
    
      // register the app with singleSPA and pass a reference to the store of the app as well as a reference to the globalEventDistributor
      singleSpa.registerApplication(
        name,
        () => SystemJS.import(appURL),
        hashPrefix(hash, wild),
        customProps
      );
```

After passing as customer props store and GlobalEventDispatcher will be available in the rootComponent passed to singleSpaReact of child app. From rootComponent it will be passed as a prop to Provider

I have referred below repo while implementing it.
https://github.com/me-12/single-spa-portal-example

Note: Currently we have are migrating to Module Federation instead of using singleSPA you can try that too.